# Matching typescript conditional and required with array and non array

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How to pass a conditional type parameters for a required param in typescript ?

```
type SomeType = string | string[]

const a: SomeType = "some string"

function person (param: string) {

}

person(a) // gives error in lint => Type 'string[]' cannot be used as an index type
```

Comment: In your code, `const a: SomeType = "some string"` is wrong, because SomeType should be and object, not a string. You should initialize a SomeType variable like, for example: `const a: SomeType =  { n: 'foobar' }` or `const a: SomeType =  { n: ['foo', 'bar'] }`. As for `function person (param: string)`, you should pass to it an argument of type string, not SomeType.

Comment: My mistake. I have made the edit. How should I force the type to string only, I'm passing a string not a string[] ?

Comment: ```person(a as string)``` will assert that a is string

Comment: [I can't reproduce your error](https://tsplay.dev/wEDDgW).  Could you please edit the code here to be a [mcve] suitable for demonstrating your problem in a standalone IDE like The TypeScript Playground?

Answer (score 0):

Try to narrow `SomeType` down to `string` by using type guard. For example:

```
type SomeType = string | string[]

const a: SomeType = "some string" as unknown as SomeType; // TypeScript is too smart, have to shadow string type

function person (param: string) {}

// Here, you have to use type guard, it helps to narrow type down to "string"
if (typeof a === 'string') {
    person(a); // TypeScript should be happy
    
}

person(a) // TypeScript should be grumpy
```

More information about narrowing is written [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html).

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=41&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgFXNAvFAzsATgSwDsBzKAH2zyOIG0BdAWAChmBjOQnKAQwC5ZEKNFEwAiLIMoESonligBXQgGtCcAO6E5ApKkgBuKAHojUPRBisCYYFHzzgcONgTdcwADRQAFtwBu0I7YvgAmGlLUUKCQzMwAZkqswPgcUJC4EloAFGBu3Aj8ONLEAJRQAN4AvrFMJlAAEhC4EF4gcAo+-oHOCliBwsQKbiFe+LbeEAA2YA7OhG644dHQYZpRzuJUMsz4cVBZy3B73CLomADkRdTnZeXMUA9pTZlZ3CWGdeaW1rZY3u2TEJQABG0F8YDAIHuj2Y1RYTHSLzexlMXys+BswQBQNBUGIuAUCEhQA).

P.S. It seems that the question should contain indexing object properties (`b['key']`), but narrowing for its keys should be suitable too.